# Request does not support ElasticSearch 6.4.3 When Using POST _Count

Tags: elasticsearch

I received an error when I tried to run POST `_count` .

This is the bodyJSON:

```
{
                "size" : "1",
                "from" : "0",
                "track_scores": true,
                "sort" : [
                         { "article_id" : "asc" }
                        ],
                "query": {
                         "filtered": {
                         "query": {
                                "query_string" : {

                                   "fields" : ["content", "title"],

                                   "query" : ` + queryEs + `
                                             }
                                         },
                                 "filter": {
                                         "range": {
                                         "article_id" : {

                            "gte": "` + intToString(s.Maxid) + `"
                                                    }
                                             }
                                         }

                     }
            }
```

}

This is the error:

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"request
>   does   not support 
>   [size]","line":2,"col":10}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"request
>   does not support [size]","line":2,"col":10},"status":400}

I wonder if my query is wrong, does anyone know if a made a mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error says size field is not supported in this request

Comment: So how do I fix this error? and what does "size" means in elasticsearch, I set the value as 1

Comment: From/ size is used for pagination and to control the number of results returned. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html. Count API returns the count of results from the search query so from/ size is invalid in this context. Remove and try.

Answer (score 0):

The **COUNT API** i.e (`_count`) itself allows us to easily execute a query and get the **number** of matches for that query so why you want extra `size` here? See more about count api [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html).

*So to be clear,*

If you want to search and get documents from your index with some limit/offset manner try [search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html) api with `from` and `size`

If you want to execute your search and get the only matched documents count/numbers then use [count](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html) api and it doesn't support extra `size` clause with so size =1 doesn't make any effect here, just avoid it when using count api.